# Async await on rendering component react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

the js code below performs the loading of a series of fields remotely and then displays them on a map, the problem is that it calls it does not wait for the await and I proceed so the data is not displayed on the map which is redirected by the component , how can I do to make the chaima wait for the response of the function before proceeding to render the map

```
import {getmarcaturegiornaliere} from "module.js";
```

**MyComponent.js**

```
  class Am4chartMap extends Component {

    async componentDidMount() {
      let map = am4core.create("map", am4maps.MapChart);
    //Load values from response this function->
    var marcature=await getmarcaturegiornaliere();       
    
    map.geodata = am4geodata_usaHigh;
    map.percentHeight = 90;
    map.dy = 10;
    let polygonSeries = map.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
    polygonSeries.useGeodata = true;
    map.homeZoomLevel = 1.2;
    map.zoomControl = new am4maps.ZoomControl();
    map.zoomControl.layout = 'horizontal';
    map.zoomControl.align = 'left';
    map.zoomControl.valign = 'bottom';
    map.zoomControl.dy = -10;
    map.zoomControl.contentHeight = 20;
    map.zoomControl.minusButton.background.fill = am4core.color("#C7D0FF");
    map.zoomControl.minusButton.background.stroke = am4core.color("#6979C9");
    map.zoomControl.minusButton.label.fontWeight = 600;
    map.zoomControl.minusButton.label.fontSize = 22;
    map.zoomControl.minusButton.scale = .75;
    map.zoomControl.minusButton.label.scale = .75;
    map.zoomControl.plusButton.background.fill = am4core.color("#C7D0FF");
    map.zoomControl.plusButton.background.stroke = am4core.color("#6979C9");
    map.zoomControl.plusButton.label.fontWeight = 600;
    map.zoomControl.plusButton.label.fontSize = 22;
    map.zoomControl.plusButton.label.align = "center";
    map.zoomControl.plusButton.scale = .75;
    map.zoomControl.plusButton.label.scale = .75;
    map.zoomControl.plusButton.dx = 5;
    let plusButtonHoverState = map.zoomControl.plusButton.background.states.create("hover");
    plusButtonHoverState.properties.fill = am4core.color("#354D84");
    let minusButtonHoverState = map.zoomControl.minusButton.background.states.create("hover");
    minusButtonHoverState.properties.fill = am4core.color("#354D84");
    let polygonTemplate = polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template;
    polygonTemplate.tooltipText = "{name}";
    polygonTemplate.fill = am4core.color("#474D84");
    polygonTemplate.stroke = am4core.color("#6979C9")
    let hs = polygonTemplate.states.create("hover");
    hs.properties.fill = am4core.color("#354D84");
    let citySeries = map.series.push(new am4maps.MapImageSeries());
    citySeries.data = marcature;
    citySeries.dataFields.value = "size";
    let city = citySeries.mapImages.template;
    city.nonScaling = true;
    city.propertyFields.latitude = "latitude";
    city.propertyFields.longitude = "longitude";
    let circle = city.createChild(am4core.Circle);
    circle.fill = am4core.color("#C7D0FF");
    circle.strokeWidth = 0;
    let circleHoverState = circle.states.create("hover");
    circleHoverState.properties.strokeWidth = 1;
    circle.tooltipText = '{tooltip}';
    circle.propertyFields.radius = 'size';

    this.map = map;    
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if(this.map) {
      this.map.dispose();
    }
  }

  render() {,.
```

**module.js**

```
//Setup server
import server from "./settings";
//Rest call axios module
const axios = require('axios').default;

export function getmarcaturegiornaliere() {

    var date="03-02-2021";
    console.log("Data: "+date);
    var listmarcature=[];

    axios.post(server.url+'/Utente/CaricamentoStoricoGiornonaliero', {
        Data: date,
        IdUtente: '3',
        CalcoloOreGiornaliere: true
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log("Response: "+response.data);
        //Vado ad iterare la response
        let data = response.data;
        for (let index in data){
          console.log("Stato: "+data[index].Longitudine);
          var datatemp={
            "latitude" : data[index].Latitudine,
            "longitude" : data[index].Longitudine,
            "size" : 5,
           "tooltip" : data[index].Stato,
          };
          listmarcature.push(datatemp);
        }
       
        }).catch(function (error) {
          console.log("Errore: "+error);
      });

      return listmarcature;
   

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `getmarcaturegiornaliere` is not async, and this is the problem.
It will always return you an empty array `[]`, because the `return listmarcature;` is executed before the `.then()` is. Therefore you return an empty array, and somewhere in the future the `.then()` will happen (and it will do nothing because you already returned).

The solution would be: Make it async.

There are some syntaxes available for that, I will bring you the best for this case:

1. Put `async` in the funciton: `export async function getmarcaturegiornaliere() {`
2. Add `await` before the `axios` call: `await axios.post(...)`